# How do I get a decent and printable pdf file of a webpage that contains mathjax?

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing, screenshot

**My attempt:**

I first went to the webpage, then pressed ctrl+shift+s. Then I pressed "save full page". Then I got a nice preview. Then I pressed download. The file downloaded as a png.
(I tried to download the file as a pdf by appending .pdf when I was naming the file, but that didn't work: I did get a pdf file; however, it won't open).

The contents of the png file became very tiny. See for yourself below:

[image]

[*Okay, when I upload the file, it doesn't seem tiny.*]

I tried to convert this png file to pdf for printing. However, [the pdf file's contents also are very tiny](https://pdfhost.io/v/vcLdmGFzR_png2pdf1). All the content has been crammed into one page. It won't be legible after I print the pdf file on paper.

How do I get a decent pdf file, which I can print on paper legibly?

**PS:** It doesn't matter what the end-file is. It could be pdf or png or whatever; I just need to be able to print in legibly on paper.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1046120/split-image-to-multiple-pages

Comment: Have you try directly to print the web page to PDF?

Comment: @RomeoNinov There's no option to download as pdf. I tried to download as pdf by appending .pdf after the name of the file, but it doesn't work. It gives me a corrupt pdf file.

Comment: Can you give an example link?

Comment: @harrymc I'd love to! However, I don't understand what example you want. Could you please elucidate?

Comment: I would like to get my hands on your webpage.

Comment: @harrymc It's a restricted website, unfortunately. The only way I could send you the website is if I send you my reg. no. and password.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic, print it as PDF

Comment: @RomeoNinov That doesn't work properly. The primary reason why I opted for the screenshot was because ctrl+p doesn't work. In the pdf, some content becomes illegible.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I took the screenshot using Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

The given Picture has not Pagination. How do you want the Pagination to occur ?

Which-ever way you choose to Paginate, you can simply take Multiple Screen Shots and Paste into a Word Document.

[[ Saving the whole thing (Either PNG or JPG or PDF) will not contain Pages and may have breaks within a Question. ]]

Eg, 1 Screen Shot for Each Question.

This Word Document can then be Printed at your convenience.

One More thought : try viewing the source, copy-pasting into new HTML Document, editing that to make nice Pages, then Printing Directly.

Why is PDF not working ?
Well, this may be because you have not set the Page Size & Page Settings Correctly.
Before saving, go to "Preferences" to select the largest Page Size. Also go to "Page SETUP" for more Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution.

**Steps:**

1. Open the .png file that you acquired after screenshotting in Microsoft paint.

[image]

2. Click on Page setup.

[image]

3. You can input the following configurations, or play around with the configurations. After inputting the configurations, click 'OK'

[image]

4. Click on print

[image]

5. Click on Microsoft XPS Document Writer. Click on 'Apply' and then click on 'print'.

[image]

6. Save the file

[image]

7. Convert the XPS file into a PDF file using any website of your choice.
8. Then print the PDF file.

[This is the end-file that I got.](https://pdfhost.io/v/hBOWy60Pq_farhan)

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Did you see that Q5 & Q11 & Q16 are broken between Pages ? [[ In my Answer , I have mentioned "Page Size" & "PAGE SETUP" !! ]] In the Process , I have used MS Word & you have used MS Paint ; Why convert to XPS & then to PDF ? [[ You can convert to PDF Directly from MS Word !! ]]

Comment: @Prem Yes, Q5,11, and 16 have been broken between pages, but screenshotting each individual question will take a lot of time. I have to print other questions as well. That's why I chose this method. For some reason, Microsoft print to pdf is missing for me in paint. That's why, I converted to XPS first and then to PDF.